# Join only with first row that refers to parent table

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have following tables:

```
A          B
id | a |   id | b
--------   -------
1  | . |   1  | 1
--------   -------
2  | . |   1  | 2
--------   -------
3  | . |   2  | 1
           -------
           2  | 2
```

B.id is a foreign key which references on A.id.
I would like to display A.id, A.a, B.b. But columns from table A should be joined only with the first row from table B which refers to A.id. I also want to select rows from table A which don't have corresponding row in table B.
So the result should looks like this:

```
A.id | A.a | B.b
----------------
  1  |  .  |  1 
----------------
  2  |  .  |  1
----------------
  3  |  .  |
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: looks like you need a `left join`.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `GROUP BY` and `LEFT JOIN` clauses :

```
SELECT A.id, A.a, B.b
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = A.id
GROUP BY A.id
ORDER BY A.id ASC
```

Comment: there is no way of knowing what you will get in B.b column - for A.id = 1 it could be 1, but also could be 2 - it may lead to bugs based on usage

Comment: I agree, but this fit exactly to the question. It's possible to use `SELECT A.id, A.a, MIN(B.b)` instead, but that's not the question purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -:

```
SELECT A.id, A.a, B.b
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT b1.id, b1.b
            FROM B b1, B b2
            WHERE b1.b < b2.b
          )B
ON A.id = B.id
GROUP BY A.id
ORDER BY A.id asc
```